# Azure SQL Express 2014 VM: Cannot update/patch SQL Express

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, windows-update, sql-server-2014

I created a VM using the standard Azure image "SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express on Windows Server 2012 R2".

I immediately ran Windows Update and all patches for the server worked but the Security Update for SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 (KB3070446) failed.  Error code: 84B30002

The Azure VM SQL Express version (SELECT @@VERSION) is:
"Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4193.9 (X64) 
    Nov 28 2015 03:44:12 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)".

This version is not a documented SQL Express 2014 version (as far as I can see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/321185#bookmark-sqlserver2014)).

I have tried installing CU 5 for SQL Express 2014 but that couldn't find a valid version of SQL Server to update.

Do you think it is non-standard version that is causing the update to fail?  I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a ticket with Microsoft and they confirmed that the SQL Express version number caused the problem.  Their response was:

> the product team has confirmed that the "SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express
>   on Windows Server 2012 R2" image was wrongly built by an internal
>   builds (12.0.4193.9).

I am not sure when they will have it fixed.  As a workaround I uninstalled SQL Express and re-installed from a public download of SQL Express.

Please NOTE: I had to install the SQL Express as a "DEFAULT" instance (MSSQLSERVER).  I tried to install the new SQL Express as a “Named” instance (SQLEXPRESS) instead of the “default” instance (MSSQLSERVER).  This didn’t work for me however.  I found that I couldn’t contact SQL Server from my other VM that was running my application.  So I installed SQL Express as a “default” instance and communication from the other VM started working!

Comment: Microsoft have now fixed the issue.  The product team has confirmed that the new image has been released to the portal now (“SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express on Windows Server 2012 R2”).